# Sqoop doesnt recognize --query param in import job command

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, sqoop2

I am trying to export data from mssql server to hive.
I am using following command to export data from Users table to hive.

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://{ip}\LOCAL_INSTANCE;database=TEST_DB;user=sa;password=****" --table "Users_Table" --create-hive-table --hive-table users_export --target-dir /cdc/export/users --append --query "select * from Users_Table"
```

I am getting following error message.

At minimum, you must specify --connect and --table
Arguments to mysqldump and other subprograms may be supplied
after a '--' on the command line.

If I remove --query param it uses default query to export data and it works fine.

I have also tried out -e parameter still getting the same error.

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use **--query** attribute. you can't mention **--table** attribute in sqoop command. because you are already mentioning it in the **FROM** clause of query parameter.

You can use below command to use **--query** attribute

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:db2://<IP_ADDR:<PORT>/<DB> --username user_name -P -m 1 --query "Select * from TABLE_NAME WHERE \$CONDITIONS AND ID = '16279320'" --target-dir /user/user_name
```

where $CONDITIONS is mandatory

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful and I couldn't find this info in the docs and it works :)